# Issues with std::put_time in C++

Tags: c++, time, std

I want to create a log file with the name mentioning the date and time and I am using Visual Studio 2013(V120). currently I am implemented a code like this but get into issues at run time. Could anyone has a method for this

```
std::string Logger::GetTimeStampWithMilliSeconds() const
{
    const auto now = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    const auto nowMs = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(now.time_since_epoch()) % 1000;

    const auto nowAsTimeT = std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(now);
    struct tm tm {};
    localtime_s(&tm, &nowAsTimeT);

    std::stringstream nowSs;
    nowSs << std::put_time(&tm, "%Y-%m-%d %T") << '.' << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(3) << nowMs.count();
    return nowSs.str();
```

The issue is replicate below.
[image]

Comment: works for me on VS2022

Comment: `using namespace` or just skipping `std` might be your enemy here. Make sure you're using right definition of `std::tm`, not C's `struct tm` (never use time.h)

Comment: `GetTimeStampWithMilliSeconds()` works normal. It seems you need to post a minimal, reproducible example like the image showed.